# What is a good way to handle multiple versioned TOS documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, versioning

App has multiple Terms Of Service-type agreements. Each agreement needs to be versioned, and have dates associated for when the agreement is valid. I'm looking at the various ActiveRecord versioning systems but I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions for this specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [gitmodel](https://github.com/pauldowman/gitmodel).  Since git excels at versioning documents, it may be a good fit here.

I haven't personally used it but it definitely looks interesting!

Comment: I don't want to add a git dependency in this project, but this is a very interesting project. Thanks, Myron!